# Resetting Select Option On Page Refresh

Tags: magento, magento2

I have a selectable dropdown on my Magento 2 cart page. I want to reset its selected option to default when we refresh the cart page or we navigate to cart page. So Whenever I refresh the cart page the default option should be reset to the default value instead of selected value.

Here is the dropdown I'm using. It is having option default it should be visible when we refresh the page

```
<select name="customCheckbox" id="commission">
<option value="0">-- Default --</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="40">40</option>
                <option value="50">50</option>
            </select>



<script>
    require([
        'ko',
        'jquery',
        'uiComponent',
        'mage/url',
        'loader'
    ], function(ko, $, Component,url){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var linkUrls = url.build('module/checkout/myValue');
            $.ajax({
                showLoader: true,
                url: linkUrls,
                data: {xyz : 1},
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    // To initialize loader
                    $('#block-shipping-plux-11').loader({
                        icon: "<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-2.gif')); ?>"
                    }); 
                    // To enable loader
                    $('#block-shipping-plux-11').loader('show');
                }
            }).done(function (data_value) {
                
                // To disable loader
                $('#block-shipping-plux-11').loader('hide');
                
                $('select[name="customCheckbox"] option[value="'+ data_value +'"]').attr("selected","selected");
                console.log('success');
                $(document).on('change','#commission', function()
                {
                
                    var linkUrls  = url.build('module/checkout/saveInQuote');
                    
                    $.ajax({
                        showLoader: true,
                        url: linkUrls,
                        data: {checkVal : $(this).val()},
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: 'json'
                    }).done(function (data) {
                        console.log('success');
                        location.reload(false)
                        
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });


    
</script>
```